# Find the E(X) where X be the number of different numbers drawn during the first four week.

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a certain lottery 5 numbers are drawn without replacement out of the set {1,2,...,90} randomly each week. Let X be the number of different numbers drawn during the first four weeks of the year. (For example, if the draws are {1,2,3,4,5}, {2,3,4,5,6}, {3,4,5,6,7} and {4,5,6,7,8} then X=8.)
Find E(X).

My work:

[image]

Comment: I am confused about how you can come up the P(Ii=1) where there is without replacement part(days) and with the replacement part(week).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems good. Basically, you want to calculate $P(I_i = 1)$. For a given round, there are $5$ numbers drawn uniformly at random (uar) without replacement. So the probability of a certain number *not* being drawn in a given round is
$$ p_5 = \frac{89}{90} \cdot \frac{88}{89} \cdot \frac{87}{88} \cdot \frac{86}{87} \cdot \frac{85}{86} = \frac{85}{90} = 1 - \frac{5}{90}. $$
(The subscript $5$ denotes that we draw $5$ numbers; in general it's a similar product of length $k$ if there are $k$ numbers drawn in one round.)
Why is this? Let's assume that we don't want to hit number $90$. Draw the first one: what's the probability that it's not $90$? Exactly $89/90$. Now draw the second: probability $88/89$. Etc, etc.

Note that different rounds are independent, so the probability that a given number doesn't appear in $4$ weeks is $p_5^4$. (You can replace the power $4$ with a general $w$ number of weeks.)

Hence the probability that the number *does* appear is $1 - p_5^4$.

Now, here's the beauty of expectation.
You might be thinking "but there are loads of correlations, so merely calculating the marginal for a single number isn't enough". But for expectation, it is! Indeed,
$$ \textstyle E(X) = E\bigl( \sum_{i=1}^{90} 1(I_i = 1) \bigr), $$
where $1(\cdot)$ is the indicator function, and hence
$$ \textstyle E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{90} P(I_i = 1) = 90 \cdot (1 - p_5^4), $$
noting that each specific number $i$ has the same probability has a different number $j$.

---

Basically, the only part where you went wrong was calculating $p_5$ as a sum, rather than a product. It's a product, because you're saying "for all of the draws, the number does not come up".

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the problem quite right.  Why isn't $p_5$ just equal to $85/90$?

Comment: Thank you! Just one question, so since if they repeat, Ii=0.

Comment: So would I think as P(Ii=1)=P(i showed up at least twice during the 4 weeks)=1-P(i showed once)-P(i didn't show up)?

Comment: @BrianTung The five numbers are chosen uniformly at random without replacement. Let's assume that we don't want to hit number 90. Draw the first one: what's the probability that it's not 90? Exactly $89/90$. Now draw the second: probability $88/89$... and whoops, I see exactly what you mean, I've been a fool and used copy+paste too recklessly! Let me correct that...

Comment: @Michelle I don't understand what you mean by "so since if they repeat, $I_i = 0$"? $I_i$ is simply the indicator function that the number shows up *at some point*. If it shows up 4 times, then $I_i = 1$; if once, then $I_i = 1$; only if it *never* shows up is $I_i = 0$.

Comment: @Sam T I see. So is P(Ii=0)=[(89C5)/(90C5)]^4?

Comment: @Michelle Yes, that is true, but it's generally better to look at these from a probabilistic point of view, rather than a combinatorial point of view. In fact, in combinatorics there's even a method called "the probabilistic method", which is basically looking at combinatorial questions as discrete probability questions, then using probabilistic techniques. It's pretty cool!

Comment: In fact, one of the first uses of this proved the existence of a certain graph by saying "choose a graph at random according to some rule", then proving that with positive probability it satisfied a condition. Hence there must exist a graph with that property, since you have non-zero chance of obtaining one when drawing at random! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method

Comment: @Michelle Does that answer all your questions? :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you!